# Getting black diamond question mark while reading csv file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a csv file with text as: The right curly single quote mark is ’ and right curly double quote mark is ”.

I am getting text as: The right curly single quote mark is � and right curly double quote mark is �.

I have used node fs module to read file with utf8 encoding as describe below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var data = fs.readFileSync('abc.csv',{encoding: 'utf8'});
  res.send(data);
})

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {});
```

Can anyone help me to fetch correct data for curly single quote and curly double quote?

Comment: try to use csv-parser => https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

Comment: Are you sure the CSV is in utf8?,. CSV is an old standard, chances are it's using codepages..

Answer (score 0):

First thing, utf8 is actually the default, so you shouldn't even need to pass it as an option

Please make sure to save the CSV file as a CSV utf-8. This will help you out to resolve the issue.

```
fs.appendFile('log.csv', '\ufeffThis is an example with accents : é � è à ', 'utf8', function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

now if you see

```
$ file -I log.csv
$ log.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Another way,
You can manually use [utf8 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) from npm to encode/decode the string.